# How to prevent user point totals from going below a threshold for a given user?

Tags: 7, userpoints

I'd like to set an absolute floor for an individual user points (using the [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) module). Specifically, to make it impossible to have a total number of user points below 1.

In Drupal 6 there was the `userpoints_no_negative` module in Userpoints_contrib, but this was removed in favour of [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) integration for 7.x (https://drupal.org/project/userpoints_contrib).

The documentation provides an example using rules to evaluate point totals with a condition of "Userpoints - Compare current Userpoints"  (https://drupal.org/node/874390), but **I am not finding this condition available**.

I'd accept any solution, be it using rules or a custom module.

---

EDIT 2/4/2014 9:17PM UTC - Example code based on ramesh babu's accepted answer:

```
/*
 * Implements hook_userpoints().
 * Checks if points at minimum threshold, corrects to 1 if pushed below limit.
 * Based on comments in Userpoints API documentation on D.O. a separate transaction
 * is made to correct for the threshold rather than modifying the points for 
 * the existing transaction.  See https://drupal.org/node/206558
 */
function mymodule_userpoints($ops, $params) {
  if ($ops == 'points before' && !isset($params['threshold'])) {
    $future_total = userpoints_get_current_points($params['uid'], 'all') + $params['points'];
    if ($future_total < 1) {
      $params['description'] = 'Minimum point correction.';
      $params['points'] = abs($future_total) + 1;
      $params['threshold'] = true;
      userpoints_userpointsapi($params);
    }
  }
}
```

The documentation for the Userpoints API on drupal.org is also a helpful resource https://drupal.org/node/206558

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the solution with custom module implementation:

implement hook_userpoints($op, $params) function in your custom module to check the user points in every transaction with two option called points before and points after.

For your thing check if the points are less than your threshold value, set your threshold value after the transaction.

for more referencehttp://api.worldempire.ch/api/userpoints/functions?page=1 check this.

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this with the following rule:

```
{ "rules_prevent_negative_points" : {
    "LABEL" : "Prevent negative points",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "Points" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "php", "rules", "userpoints_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "userpoints_event_points_awarded_after" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "php_eval" : { "code" : "$num_pts = userpoints_get_current_points($userpoints_transaction->uid, \u0027all\u0027);\r\nif ($num_pts \u003C 0) {return TRUE;}" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "userpoints_rules_get_current_points" : {
          "USING" : { "user" : [ "userpoints-transaction:user" ], "tid" : "all" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "loaded_points" : { "negative_amount" : "Negative amount of points." } }
        }
      },
      { "data_calc" : {
          "USING" : { "input_1" : [ "negative-amount" ], "op" : "*", "input_2" : "-1" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "result" : { "pos_value" : "Positive value." } }
        }
      },
      { "data_calc" : {
          "USING" : { "input_1" : [ "pos-value" ], "op" : "+", "input_2" : "1" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "result" : { "result" : "result" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_convert" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "integer",
            "value" : [ "result" ],
            "rounding_behavior" : "down"
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "conversion_result" : { "points" : "Points needed to become 1" } }
        }
      },
      { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
          "user" : [ "userpoints-transaction:user" ],
          "points" : [ "points" ],
          "tid" : "0",
          "entity" : [ "" ],
          "description" : "Prevent negative amount of points.",
          "operation" : "Add",
          "display" : 0,
          "moderate" : "approved"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Simply import it at `Configuration > Workflow > Rules`.

Comment: +1 for rules implementation!  One small correction to the condition I think is necessary: `$num_pts = userpoints_get_current_points($userpoints_transaction->uid, 'all');`
`if ($num_pts < 1) {return TRUE;} else {return FALSE;}`

Comment: You're correct the `else` is irrelevant. What I believe is necessary is to use `$userpoints_transaction->uid` to pull back the userpoints total for the the user who created the content instead of the flagging user which is returned via `global $user`.

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 7, there is no Rules Condition related to the current total user points for a user. Except by using custom PHP code as in this example (which is similar to the Rules condition in Jeroen's answer, and which you could use in a Rules Condition *Execute custom PHP code*, e.g. to do some type of comparison):

```
global $user;
$current_points = userpoints_get_current_points($user->uid, 'all');
if ($current_points < 0) {return TRUE;}
```

However, there is a Rules Action "***Load user points of a user***", whereas you can ask for either a specific category, or for all categories together. This Rules Action provides a Rules variable (for which you can specify its name and description) which contains the amount of user points for the requested category. You can then use this variable in subsequent Rules Actions.

If you then want to use that variable within a Rules Condition, you have 2 ways of doing so:

- Include the condition in a Rules Component, whereas you trigger the execution of that Rules Component via a Rules Action following the "Load user points of a user" (and passing the variable containing the amount of user points as a variable for the Rules Component).
- Use the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module, so that you can specify Rules Conditions within Rules Actions.

Here is a basic example that displays a message about the current total user points for a user, after the user performed an update of some node (= the Rules Event, which you can change to any Rules Event that you want ... eg: replace it by "Drupal is initializing" to display the message on every path of your site):

```
{ "rules_display_userpoints_after_updating_content" : {
    "LABEL" : "Display userpoints after updating content",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "userpoints_rules", "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_update" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "userpoints_rules_get_current_points" : {
          "USING" : { "user" : [ "site:current-user" ], "tid" : "all" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "loaded_points" : { "total_points" : "Number of points in all categories together" } }
        }
      },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "You now have [total-points:value] points" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Use the Rules UI to import the above rule in your own site if you want.

To actually ensure the amount of user points is never below your threshold, perform Rules Actions similar to the Rules Actions shown in Jeroen's answer (using a Rules Component, or Conditional Rules, as explained above).

With that, you have another [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) based solution **which does not require custom PHP code** (in your Rules Condition).