# How to prevent negative userpoints transactions and checkout?

Tags: userpoints

Some remarks on this issue were found in the question about [How to prevent user point totals from going below a threshold for a given user?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102142/how-to-prevent-userpoint-totals-from-going-below-a-threshold-for-a-given-user-in) and related topics.

But there is also a question how to prevent checkout when a user tries buying a product which costs more than the user has on his balance/userpoints account.

Is there a universal solution (or not unique) to this problem for transactions and checkout at the same time?

Comment: I suppose that negative transactions are allowed for the admin all the time ... But for usual users are not.

Comment: You are using [Drupal commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) and [Commerce Userpoints](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_userpoints)? Please edit and add such details to your question.

Comment: That's correct.